# Connect Wordpress and react front-end

Tags: block-editor

Some people say to build React as front-end it is neccesary to use wordpress as headless CRM, but I wonder what is the difference between such a solution and using gutenberg to create subpage templates? This solution seems simpler because I don't have to use REST API or GraphQL to transfer data, I also save on hosting. I'm just curious about the difference in quality.

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/

Comment: In general, given the flexibility of either approach the "quality" achievable by either is similar if not on-par, and hosting requirements for similar types of sites built to leverage either should also be roughly equivalent. But simply using Gutenberg out of the box is not providing you with a React-based front-end unless you're using a theme which is explicitly built to do so. So if having a front-end running React is optional and the other two stated points aren't really factors I find relevant to the choice, I'm not really sure how to make heads or tails of this question.

Comment: Building templates with the block editor is not using React for the front end. It's using a React-based tool to create HTML that is served from a database using PHP. They are not the same thing. You can use React on a WordPress site without using WordPress as a headless CMS, but that has nothing to do with using the block editor to create templates.

Comment: I notice that i can deregister jquery and enqueque react in front end (it has react in wp element).  There is a Such big difference if i take datę from phpadmin or from json (rest API) or graphql?